# ARM Deployment error: Unable to freeze secondary namespace before creating pairing, this is probably because secondary namespace is not empty

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-resource-group

I have two premium Service bus instances deployed manually through the azure portal. They don't have geo-recovery alias configured and the service bus instances have been operational for about a year.

Now, I'm trying automate the deployment process of these service bus instances and also add a georecovery  alias resource to it as follows:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "serviceBusNamespaceName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the Service Bus namespace"
      }
    },
    "serviceBusQueueName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the Queue"
      }
    },
    "serviceBusLocation": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "sku": {
      "type": "object",
      "defaultValue": "Standard"
    },
    "serviceBusTopicName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "serviceBusSubscriptionName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "isAliasEnabled": {
      "type": "bool"
    },
    "isQueueCreationEnabled": {
      "type": "bool"
    },
    "aliasName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "partnerNamespace": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "defaultSASKeyName": "RootManageSharedAccessKey",
    "authRuleResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/authorizationRules', parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'), variables('defaultSASKeyName'))]",
    "sbVersion": "2017-04-01"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2018-01-01-preview",
      "name": "[parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/Namespaces",
      "location": "[parameters('serviceBusLocation')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('sku').name]",
        "tier": "[parameters('sku').tier]",
        "capacity": "[parameters('sku').capacity]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "zoneRedundant": false
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
          "name": "[parameters('aliasName')]",
          "type": "disasterRecoveryConfigs",
          "condition": "[parameters('isAliasEnabled')]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/', parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "partnerNamespace": "[parameters('partnerNamespace')]"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm using the same template to deploy the primary and secondary instances separately. Note that the disasterRecoveryConfigs resource will only be deployed when it's the primary instance.

This template **successfully** deploys the secondary namespace, but the **primary namespace deployment fails** with the following error:

> Unable to freeze secondary namespace before creating pairing, this is
> probably because secondary namespace is not empty.

Which is correct i.e. the secondary namespace has a couple of topics/subscriptions and queues already created. I don't want to delete them and just want to pair the primary and secondary namespaces.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with the Service Bus Geo-Recovery ARM Template. I read the exception closely; its state that the secondary namespace is not empty means we have to delete the topic and queue from the secondary namespace, then run the template again. It will work and create the topic and queue again based on the primary namespace.

But if you run the template a second time, you will get a different exception, which is that the secondary namespace cannot be updated (since it’s in geo-pairing). It’s strange, but by design, you cannot update the secondary namespace while it’s in Geo Pairing, and even if you remove Geo Pairing, your secondary namespace should be empty without any instances such as Topic, Queue, etc.

**How to overcome this?**

Lets consider, now I wanted to add the Topic or Queue in existing deployment by using the ARM template then, you will ran into the issue when your template is in the pipeline or anywhere and needs to run multiple times and update the existing primary namespace.

**1. Quick Fix (one time only second time manually again you have to do the following steps)**

- Login to the Azure Portal
- Go to the your primary Service bus Namespace
- Click on the Geo-Recovery option under setting section
- At the right hand side at the top find the option break pairing and
  click on it.

[image]

It will break the pairing & **if you not follow this step you will get the exception, Secondary Namespaces can not be updated**

- Next, delete the secondary Namespace instance or Namespace and run
  the pipeline. it will work.

**If you not follow above step then you will get error unable to freeze secondary Namespace.**

The above is the one time fix, if you run template again you have to repeat above process manually again.

**2. Automation using CI-CD DevOps Pipeline or CLI or PowerShell**

The most of the time ARM templates runs in the pipeline and there is option to break the pairing using the Azure CLI or PowerShell. You should consider the adding two task in the YAML file

- First Task, to break the Pairing

Azure CLI

```html
az servicebus georecovery-alias break-pair --resource-group myresourcegroup --namespace-name primarynamespace --alias myaliasname
```

PowerShell

```html
Set-AzureRmServiceBusGeoDRConfigurationBreakPair -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup -Name $aliasname -Namespace $primarynamespace
```

- Second Task, to delete the secondary namespace instances (topic,
  Queue) or delete entire Namespace.

PowerShell

```html
Remove-AzServiceBusNamespace -ResourceGroup Default-ServiceBus-WestUS -NamespaceName SB-Example1
```

To remove Topic or Queue instead of Namespace, refer the following documentation.

[Azure Service Bus Management Common PowerShell commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.servicebus/remove-azservicebusnamespace?view=azps-7.1.0)

Also if you are running template locally, you can add small script or CLI command prior to run your template.

**Does it affect on ConnectionString or Data after deleting Secondary Namespace or instances?**

Its valid question, what will happens to the connection string or data since some clients are already using it, The answer is connection string wont be change if we delete the secondary namespace because in Geo recovery scenario we are supposed to be use alias connection string so there is no impact on existing customers.

Regarding the second question about the data, the answer is secondary namespace wont store any data it has only the meta data, meaning in the case of failover secondary namespace start working.

So during the deployment deleting secondary namespace instances or namespace wont impact on anything.

**Is there any better option?**

Might be you are thinking, why should I follow such a long process but the above problem because of the Geo Recovery design (service bus, event hub, event grid etc.) and there is no other option.

I hope Microsoft will come up with some better approach in the future.

Comment: There is a [github issue for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63179557/arm-deployment-error-unable-to-freeze-secondary-namespace-before-creating-pairi) which is closed unfortunately. I asked them to reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to [create a pairing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-geo-dr) between a primary namespace with a private endpoint and a secondary namespace without a private endpoint, the pairing will fail.

You could refer to this [template](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/101-servicebus-create-namespace-geo-recoveryconfiguration/) allows you to configure Service Bus Geo-disaster recovery alias.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "serviceBusNamespaceNamePrimary": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of Service Bus namespace"
      }
    },
    "serviceBusNamespaceNameSecondary": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of Service Bus namespace"
      }
    },
    "aliasName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of Geo-Recovery Configuration Alias "
      }
    },
    "locationSecondaryNamepsace": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "South Central US",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location of Secondary namespace"
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location of Primary namespace"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "defaultSASKeyName": "RootManageSharedAccessKey",
    "defaultAuthRuleResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/authorizationRules', parameters('serviceBusNamespaceNamePrimary'), variables('defaultSASKeyName'))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
      "name": "[parameters('serviceBusNamespaceNameSecondary')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/Namespaces",
      "location": "[parameters('locationSecondaryNamepsace')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Premium",
        "tier": "Premium",
        "capacity": 4
      },
      "tags": {
        "tag1": "value1",
        "tag2": "value2"
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/Namespaces",
      "dependsOn": [ "[concat('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/', parameters('serviceBusNamespaceNameSecondary'))]" ],
      "name": "[parameters('serviceBusNamespaceNamePrimary')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Premium",
        "tier": "Premium",
        "capacity": 4
      },
      "tags": {
        "tag1": "value1",
        "tag2": "value2"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
          "name": "[parameters('aliasName')]",
          "type": "disasterRecoveryConfigs",
          "dependsOn": [ "[concat('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/', parameters('serviceBusNamespaceNamePrimary'))]" ],
          "properties": {
            "partnerNamespace": "[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/Namespaces', parameters('serviceBusNamespaceNameSecondary'))]"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "NamespaceDefaultConnectionString": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[listkeys(variables('defaultAuthRuleResourceId'), '2017-04-01').primaryConnectionString]"
    },
    "DefaultSharedAccessPolicyPrimaryKey": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[listkeys(variables('defaultAuthRuleResourceId'), '2017-04-01').primaryKey]"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't have any private endpoints created on the service bus instances. The Networking page looks the same for both the primary/secondary instances.It has the "Selected Networks" option selected by default as shown in the picture here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/media/service-bus-ip-filtering/default-networking-page.png